# Combining & (AND) and | (OR) with a > comparison

Tags: r

OK, I guess this is really basic, but I'm confused by the results. Perhaps can someone explain to me how R interprets what I typed.
I was just playing around in R, and I wanted to check if & and | worked as I expected them to, as "and" or "or". Here is what I tried:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 7:-2
rbind(x, y, x&y>5, y&x>5, x|y>5)
```

This is what I got :

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
x    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
y    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    0   -1    -2
     1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
     0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    1     1
     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
```

So I understood my mistake, modified to "x>5 & y>5" and "x>5 | y>5", and got the results I would expect.

But can anybody explain to me what R understands with my initial input, and why x&y and y&x don't even give the same result! If someone was kind enough to point out what it means?..

Comment: This is not strange behavior at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's to do with *operator precedence*. `>` binds tighter than `&`.

So your computation is equivalent to `x & (y > 5)` which, in words means, `x` is non-zero and `y` is greater than 5.

Comment: OK! Thanks! Like I said, it was bound to be quite simple, but I couldn't understand the how and why.

Answer (score 0):

`x&y>5` is interpreted as `x` is not `FALSE` and `y>5`. Note that `0` will evaluate as `FALSE` .

Answer (score 0):

Well, note that `x&y` and `y&x` *do* give the same results

```
all(x&y == y&x)
# [1] TRUE
```

the difference comes when you add the `>` part. This has to do with operator precedence in R. See the `?Syntax` help page for the order of operations. It turns out that `>` has higher precedence than `&` so you're really doing

```
x&(y>5)
y&(x>5)
```

so you will get different results.